# Wrapper won't cover whole screen

Tags: html, css, wrapper

for some reason the wrapper on my code wont cover the whole screen and I can't figure out why, here is what the code looks like : http://goo.gl/4RtF5o

The wrapper (blue) won't go the top of the page, id prefer to not add CSS to body tag as I'm not sure on how animating a fade in on that will affect the rest of the content.

Comment: Use the stack snippet to show relevant code. That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to your #wrap css:

```
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! much obliged

Answer (score 1):

Your blue background "wrapper" is actually `div.content` (class="content") which goes after `div#head` and `div#subhead` - and those are of white background, and they push the `div.content` lower.

If you want everything blue, change classes for either `body` or both `.head` and `.subhead`

Answer (score 0):

Add to .upani

```
.upani {
  float: left;
  width:100%;
}
```